# How do I fix these issues for my segmented video files?

Tags: macos, streaming, encoding

[image]

I'm using an .m3u8 file uploaded to Amazon Web Services for HLS streaming. When I create an HLS report for it, it shows that there are several must fix issues present.

I'm fairly new to validating and segmenting videos and such so I need to go by what's available in terms of documentation online but there's very little help or resources online that explain how to resolve these issues.

My current approach is using FFMpeg on Windows in order to encode videos and on a Mac using mediafilesegmenter to divide them into .ts files and then use variantplaylistcreator to make a master playlist .m3u8 file. If someone could look at the attached image and tell me how I could possibly fix these problems with the tools I have then that would be very helpful.